# How to cluster data with discrete binary attributes?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, cluster-analysis

In my data, there are ten millions of binary attributes,
But only some of them are informative, most of them are zeros.

Format is like as following:

```
data  attribute1 attribute2 attribute3 attribute4   .........
A          0          1           0         1       .........
B          1          0           1         0       .........
C          1          1           0         1       .........
D          1          1           0         0       .........
```

What is a smart way to cluster this?
I know K-means clustering. But I don't think it's suitable in this case. 
Because the binary value makes distances less obvious.
And it will suffer form the curse of high-dimensionality.
Eeve if I cluster based on those few informative attribute, it's still to many attributes.

I think the decision tree is nice to cluster this data. 
But it's a Classification algorithm!

What can I do?

Comment: Hi there. Just wondering what might the attributes represent and if they make much sense? And maybe hamming distance in this case will do better jobs.

Comment: My thought: still use k-means; distance measure: hamming distance; representative update: take mode of each attribute... Only a random guess

Comment: Thx Ray! Hamming Distance is a informative idea for me! Those attributes are user clicks of a URL. That's why there are so many URLs! They're actually positive integer attributes, but most of the numbers are either 1 or 0. So I treat them like binary.

Comment: You are welcome! Actually I am pretty interested in your task. Do update me if you find anything fun! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered **frequent itemset mining** instead?

K-means definitely is a bad idea, but hierarchical clustering may work when using an appropriate distance function such as jaccard, hamming, dice, ...

Anyway, **what is a cluster**? The choice of algorithm needs to fit to the kind of cluster you want to find. On binary data, centroid-based methods such as k-means don't make sense, as centroids are not too meaningful.

If the data are "shopping cart" type of information, consider using frequent itemset mining, as it allows discovering overlapping subsets.

Comment: Thx! But My purpose is to group different users. How does frequent itemset mining group users?

Comment: This would yield group as in: "shares the same frequent itemset". If you want to have groups based on similar interests, this seems to be a good choice of "clusters". (But you need to be able to deal with *overlapping* clusters, and singletons).

Comment: That's what I am wondering about. I don't have knowledge about dealing with those. But you give me new keywords "Clustering Similar Interests". I can get more information with that. Thanks!