# Finding Common Groups in Data / Clustering

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis

**Grouping Data**

I have a group of items that I want to segment into clusters based on how they typically appear together. For example, if I have the following data:

```
{a:1, b:1, c:0, d:0}
{a:1, b:1, c:0, d:0}
{a:1, b:1, c:1, d:0}
{a:0, b:0, c:1, d:1}
```

We could group a and b together because they always have the same values as each other. C and D would each be in their own clusters, so we'd end up with 3 clusters that can represent this data 100% accurately.

Furthermore, I'd like to sacrifice accuracy to reduce the number of subgroups. For example, with the above data set, we can group A and B into a cluster with no loss in accuracy, and C and D with a slight loss in accuracy.

Basically, I'd like to group the data into a given number of optimal clusters, and be able to calculate the loss in accuracy by doing so.

**Initial Thoughts**

I took a class on machine learning several years ago, so I know enough to be dangerous, but I am at a loss for where to start with this. [Some form of clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unsupervised_learning), such as mixture models, or hierarchical clustering appear to be the correct direction?

Comment: you may find this community somewhat useful http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Leo Yeah, I think it looks more relevant over there. Should I just repost it?

Comment: I believe you'll find your answer there. Stackoverflow usually works better for specific programming problems.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to cluster data with discrete binary attributes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20416459/how-to-cluster-data-with-discrete-binary-attributes)

Comment: Think you're looking for a Principal Components Analysis. You can do this trivially in many languages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is often called *item set mining* , *association rule learning*, or *affinity analysis*.

The (poorly named) [Apriori algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apriori_algorithm) is one of the earlier and most commonly used algorithms for such analysis, and includes methods of "sacrificing accuracy" to reduce the number of subgroups.

Now that you have the proper vocabulary, you should be able to find many tutorials and implementations of APriori since it is a 'classical' algorithm/solution, as well as more algorithms for such work.

Comment: Thank you, this definitely looks like the right direction to go in. For other people that find this question, here's another helpful link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20416459/how-to-cluster-data-with-discrete-binary-attributes?rq=1